# How do I structure a command system using event in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, structure

I've tried searching the answer beforehand but I don't know what keyword should I search to find what I wanted.

Here is the question.

I am trying to make a simple turn based strategy game with AS3. I have 2 classes being used:

1. The "Main" class for starting up the game
2. The "Castle" class that creates a castle with a function to dispatch an "Attack" Event .

When the game start the Main class (The main gameplay screen) will create 4 different instance of the Castle class. Each of those castle will have the option to attack other castles.

I would like to set up a system that functions like this:

1. Main class contains a event listener to hear for "Attack CastleX" (X is variable, it changes according to which castle is being attacked)
2. Castle will be dispatching event called maybe "Attack Castle#1" or "Attack Castle#2" to indicate which castle it wants to attack.
3. Main class then receives the "Attack Castle#1" or "Attack Castle#2" event. And decrease the Health Point of the targeted Castle.

My problem here is that i don't know how to set up an event listener that can listen to both the event "Attack Castle#1" and "Attack Castle#2" or "Attack Castle#3/4/5/6/7".

I have a feeling that I might have to use String for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to dispatch an event which has a property referring to the Castle you want to attack.

That's easy enough to achieve when you create your own event:

```
public class CastleEvent extends Event
{
    public static const ATTACK:String = "attack";

    // Linked to the castle.
    public var castle:int;

    public function CastleEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false):void
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

When your Castle starts attacking:

```
var attack:CastleEvent = new CastleEvent(CastleEvent.ATTACK);
attack.castle = 2; // Specify the castle to attack.
dispatchEvent(attack);
```

And then the listener in the main class can deal with the appropriate Castle:

```
private function _manageAttack(e:CastleEvent):void
{
    var targetCastle:int = e.castle;

    // Do stuff to the targetCastle.
    //
    //
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly and I've learnt alot from your example! Thanks alot Marty!